# “The lengths of two lines are 4 meters each.”

Tags: each-every

> The lengths of two lines are 4 meters each.

> Each length of two lines is 4 meters

Do two sentences mean the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither expression is idiomatic. I suggest instead,

> Each line is 4 meters long.